# "Tener" vs "tener de plazo"

Tags: gramática

¿Cual es la diferencia de significado entre "tener" y " tener de" en el siguiente contexto? O sea, ¿no se puede decir, por ejemplo, "tener plazo hasta ..."? ¡Muchas gracias!

"[El público tiene de plazo hasta el 16 de marzo de 2003 para presentar sus observaciones y sus ideas.](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/detail/es/IP_03_197)"

Comment: tener un plazo de x hubiera sido mejor.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El verbo "**Tener**", tiene el significado de asir, sujetar, mantener algo, poseer, ser dueño de alguna cosa, entre otras acepciones. La historia del verbo "tener" es larga, de hecho antiguamente el verbo "haber" era el más utilizado para expresar el mismo sentido que "tener", hoy en día aún quedan resquicios de tiempos pasados.

Por otra parte la perífrasis "**tener de**", parecida parcialmente a  "tener que" o "tener en", su significado normalmente participa o se relaciona con algún tipo de característica, condición, obligatoriedad, necesidad, probabilidad o voluntad existentes. Así podemos decir;

- "tener un plazo" El público **tiene de plazo** hasta el día 16 de Marzo para presentar sus ideas. La característica de este anuncio o presentación de ideas, con respecto a otras, es que termina el día 16 de Marzo, y por otra parte también es voluntad del que lo ha propuesto que después de ese día ya no se puedan presentar más ideas por parte del público.
- Lo que "**tenía de su padre**" era el carácter. El hijo tiene una característica acentuada que lo relaciona con el que tenía su padre en la misma forma de ser.
- Yo no **tengo** nada **de** listo. / Yo no **tengo** nada **de** tonto. La característica que posee o que no posee es la de ser listo o tonto.
- Ramón **tiene** mucho **de** artista bohemio. Ramón tiene una vena, característica o condición artística.
- Ese cantante me gusta por lo que **tiene de** romántico. El cantante tiene una característica que sobresale entre otras, que es muy romanticismo.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por sus explicaciones, Diego!

Comment: ¡ Gracias a ti !

Answer (score 1):

En el contexto que mencionas, la diferencia entre “tener” y “tener de” es que “tener de” se utiliza para indicar un límite de tiempo. Por lo tanto, no se puede decir simplemente “tener plazo hasta …”, ya que la preposición “de” es necesaria para indicar el límite de tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Las dos oraciones:

1. El público tiene de plazo hasta el 16 de marzo de 2003 para presentar sus observaciones y sus ideas.

y

2. El público tiene plazo hasta el 16 de marzo de 2003 para presentar sus observaciones y sus ideas.

son correctas.

Existe entre ellas una diferencia sintáctica, no de sentido.

En (1), "de plazo" puede entenderse como equivalente a "como plazo", y puede ubicarse después del plazo propiamente dicho:

1a. El público tiene hasta el 16 de marzo de 2003 **de plazo / como plazo** para presentar sus observaciones y sus ideas.

En cambio, en (2) toda la frase "plazo hasta el 16 de marzo de 2003" es objeto directo.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por su respuesta! Tengo una pregunta más: ¿Hay otra forma de decir "como plazo"? ¡Gracias otra vez!

Comment: Se puede directamente evitar la frase y decir: El público tiene hasta el 16 de marzo de 2003 para ... (o El público tiene como fecha límite el 16 de enero de 2003 para ...)

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!